# How to make a multi-species vegetation density transect plot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to make a figure displaying the cover density of multiple species along a transect. Something along the style of the image here. Where there are horizontal rows of each species and at each point along the transect a value of density (I will then draw the elevation plot along the top).

[old figure I am trying to update/replicate, ignore the scale legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8glT.png)

Here is an example data set of one transect, with hypothetical cover density of six species taken at 10 quadrats.

````
Species <- c("S1", "S2", "S3","S4","S5","S6")
Q1 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,0)
Q2 <- c(0,0,1,2,1,0)
Q3 <- c(0,0,1,3,2,4)
Q4 <- c(0,2,1,4,2,4)
Q5 <- c(0,3,0,2,1,4)
Q6 <- c(1,4,0,1,2,5)
Q7 <- c(2,5,0,0,1,1)
Q8 <- c(3,1,0,1,2,0)
Q9 <- c(4,0,0,0,1,0)
Q10 <- c(1,0,0,0,2,0)
df= data.frame(Species, Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6,Q7,Q8,Q9,Q10)```
````

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I was going to say something similar, although done in a slightly different way...

```
df2 <- gather(df, key = "Point", value = "Density", -1)

ggplot(df2, aes(x = Point, y = Density))+
  geom_col()+
  theme_classic()+
  facet_grid(rows = vars(Species))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. You may need to reorder the quadrats on the x axis though: at the moment you have Q1, Q10, Q2, etc

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

pivot_longer(df, -1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(name, unique(name)), value)) + 
  geom_col(fill = "gray10") +
  facet_grid(Species~.) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.2, 0.2)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(50, 20, 20, 20),
        panel.spacing = unit(30, "points"),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 16))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>